# How can I check the slope at a certain point in a graph in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

Hos can I find the point in an LTspice graph where the slope is -1?

Example:

[image]

Is there is a way to find out, or do I just need to guess?

Comment: The slope will have units. Depending on the units you want, the location of "-1" will be different. For example, the location where volts/hour is -1 will be different from the location where volts/second is -1. What are the units? That said, you can use the .MEAS card to find the location. Have you read the help docs on .MEAS, yet?

Comment: i read it and i didn't understand how i can find the slope yet :/

Comment: You can use something like this: ".meas TRAN MYVALUE FIND time WHEN d(V(out))=-1 TD=15m CROSS=1" The "TD" value is when to "start looking" for the value.  You can set that to 0, if you want.

Comment: If you zoom in you might be able to visually estimate the slope. Might be able to export the data. Don't think there is a slope tool for the waveform viewer.

Comment: @mkeith There is; you can plot the derivative with the D() function.

Comment: @Hearth, that sounds like an answer!

Comment: No units for the horizontal scale? Is this a DC analysis of some treshold, comparator or high gain diff.amp circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this simple, I'll use a sine/cosine wave to analyze. I'll use a realistic circuit (except that there's nothing done to manage the gain roll-off at higher frequencies.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOCIAQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage gain of the above single-BJT common-emitter degenerative and bootstrapped stage is \$A_V=-10\$. Suppose I use an input signal of \$500\:\text{mVp}\$ and \$f=2\:\text{kHz}\$. This means the output should be \$5\:\text{Vp}\$ and should, as a function of time, representable as \$V_\text{OUT}\left(t\right)=5\:\text{V}\cdot\operatorname{cos}\left(2\pi\,f\,t\right)\$.

The derivative is \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\,t}V_\text{OUT}\left(t\right)=-2\pi\,f\cdot5\:\text{V}\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(2\pi\,f\,t\right)\$. Since the maximum possible value for the sine is 1 or -1, then \$\left(-62.8\frac{\text{kV}}{\text{s}}=-2\pi\,f\cdot5\:\text{V}\right)\le\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\,t}V_\text{OUT}\left(t\right)\le \left(2\pi\,f\cdot5\:\text{V}=62.8\frac{\text{kV}}{\text{s}}\right)\$.

Put the above schematic into LTspice. Don't forget to add a voltage source for the \$30\:\text{V}\$ supply. Also don't forget to set up \$V_1\$ so that it says "SINE(0 500m 2k)" and then set up a .TRAN card:

```
.tran 0 50m 0 1u
```

At this point you should be able to run a simulation and see the resulting curve produced at the node labeled ***Output*** on the above schematic.

Now. Let's say you want to find the place where \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\,t}V_\text{OUT}\left(t\right)\$ transitions through a value of \$10\frac{\text{kV}}{\text{s}}\$ (which is in the range of possibility.) Then you might add the following card:

```
.meas TRAN MYRESULT FIND time WHEN d(v(Output))=10000 TD=15m CROSS=1
```

That just says that on a .TRAN run that you want to create something called MYRESULT which is the ***time*** for the first moment when the derivative of the output crosses through the value of 10000 after 15 milliseconds into the run.

Try it. Then go to the menu and select "View/SPICE error log" to get the error log displayed. Within it, you should be able to find a line similar to:

```
MYRESULT: time=0.0151429 at 0.0151429
```

This tells you approximately where the event took place (after where TD says to start looking, of course.)

It's not much more complicated than that.

Comment: Another quick, but not very precise method is to use the zoom function through click&drag, which will tell the differences in the X and Y axes, and the slope.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I've done that. But soon decided to learn how to use .meas. You can drag out a rectangle on the plot and it will compute slopes for you. But it gets a little tedious. .meas helped me in a few places and I use it more than before.

Comment: Far from me to dismiss the power of `.meas`, that's as precise as it gets. Just thought I'd mention the alternative, that's all. A pity to see downvotes which (most likely) come from mild malice, themselves caused (again, most likely) by not providing the answer it was expected. Couldn't help noticing this user is another alias from similar types of questions under different names (or, at least, same picture is used).

Answer (score 0):

LTspice does allow post-processing of a TRANsient run for a slope measurement. You can use the **.OP** button to add the slope measurement. In this case, the result **slope_V(out)** shows up in the **SPICE ERROR LOG** window:

```
.meas TRAN slope_V(out) MAX d(V(out))/d((time))
```

Note that a small time step is required for an accurate result. When TRAN time step was increased from 1ns to 1us, the **slope_V(out)** result changed from **999.764** to **996.096**[image: LTspice TRAN circuit schematic example]